# Can only open https:// websites in OSX

Tags: macos, networking, connection

I can't open non secure sites (any direction with hhtp://) . Only works in https sites.

I Tried the following with no results except in safe mode.

-Diferent browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).

-Deleting Preferences and system configuration.

-Reboot in safe mode (**Thats Works!!**).

-Checking the proxies configuration (i haven't proxies)

-Changing the DNS.

-Turning off/on wifi.

-Repair directory permissions.

-Flushing DNS Cache.

-Reseting Router.

Anyone that can help me?. I am little desperate.

Thks in advance

Comment: Why downvote this?! I just encountered the same problem these days, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem and it was very very strange.

I found the following " com.erythropoieic.net - preferences.plist " file under the "Library / LaunchDaemons / " folder. This file called this script " change_net_settings.sh " changing the network Properties.  I removed that files and thew problem was solved.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/activity?streamSource=connections&streamID=12738815

Comment: I just resolved this issue with chroot's solution and found the same root cause! **change_net_settings.sh** https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7521966

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same with all browsers on my macbook pro. This is a malware issue. Please run anti- malware clean up using the malwarebytes.

Answer (score -1):

This is a frequent problem when updating Microsoft OS or Internet Explorer.   Seems the update flips the LAN Connection setting, so:

Start Internet Explorer
Click on Setting (upper right)
Click the Tools button
Click on Internet Options
Click on Connections tab
Click on LAN settings
UNCHECK Proxy Server for your LAN

Select OKAY

Validate you can now get to websites without having to manually enter https://

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in FireFox (45.X ESR) from Linux.   I could only browse to sites if I used https://.   If I used http:// or www:// I got redirected to  dnssearch.com (my ISP is Time Warner).      It turn's my issue was with how Firefox was configured to connect to the Internet.   To resolve this issue in Firefox, click the open menu icon and select Options (or Preferences in older versions) and then select Advanced.  On the Advanced page, click the Network tab.  On the Network page, click Settings (For how Firefox connects to the internet).   Under Configure Proxies to Access the internet, there a several radio buttons.  In my case, the Manual proxy configuration was checked.   I changed this and check: No proxy.   This resolved my issue.  I could then access any site as normal.

Comment: I've never heard of "www://" before.